# Aruba-MySQL: can't create/change table to engine=INNODB

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys, aruba

We have our database stored in aruba (mysql.aruba.it) where there is a table called "task". Because of many changes in the requirements we decided to drop the table and create it again from 0 with different fields and constraints. The problem is that MySQL/Aruba won't let us create the table anymore. Or better, we can create another task table only with engine MyISAM but we need INNODB because we will use contraints and foreign keys in the table. So I have tried to create a MyISAM table and then convert it into INNODB but I get an error like this:

```
ALTER TABLE  `task` ENGINE = INNODB
#1025 - Error on rename of './Sql689345_4/#sql-6962_1891f' to './Sql689345_4/task' (errno: -1)
```

I don't know why there is this problem with this table: for other tables we have we can drop them and re-create them as many times as we want. 
Is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Not all Aruba databases accept InnoDB tables; verify on the "Engine" link inside the control panel if INNODB is in white (engaged) or in grey (disengaged); if your database does not support InnoDB tables you can ask a new database supporting InnoDB for free, opening an assistance ticket.

In order to convert a table from MyIsam to InnoDB, is not a good practice to use the command ALTER TABLE, I suggest to export your table in a .sql file, CREATE a new table with the required structure and the InnoDB engine, and then import the data from .sql file.